# Placement of Y labels plotly python horizontal barchart

Tags: python, plotly-python, axis-labels

I'm looking for a way to get the y labels of a plotly horizontal barchart above the grouped bars. What i'm looking for is:

[image]

```
import pandas as pd 
import plotly.graph_objects as go

test_df = pd.DataFrame({'component':['BAR 1','BAR 2','BAR 3'],'mean':[7.4,7.8,6.5],'mean_proj':[6.8,7.9,8.4]})

def barchart2(df,x1,x2,y):
    fig = go.Figure()
    fig.add_trace(go.Bar(name=x1,x=df[x1],y=df[y],orientation='h',hoverinfo=None,marker_color='#221435')),
    fig.add_trace(go.Bar(name=x2,x=df[x2],y=df[y],orientation='h',hoverinfo=None,marker_color='rgb(55,177,140)')),      
    fig.update_xaxes(showgrid=False, zeroline=False)
    fig.update_yaxes(showgrid=False, zeroline=False)
    fig.update_layout(paper_bgcolor='rgba(0,0,0,0)',plot_bgcolor='rgba(0,0,0,0)',bargap=0.20,margin=dict(t=30,b=5,l=25,r=0))
    fig.update_layout(barmode='group')
    return fig.write_html('test.html',auto_open=True)

barchart2(test_df,'mean','mean_proj','component')
```

Comment: After viewing the [documentiations](https://plotly.com/python/reference/layout/yaxis/#layout-yaxis) on how to configure the yaxis, I find no predefined approach for this.

Comment: do you mean the tick labels or the trace names to be inserted where your yellow arrows are?   i.e. insert "mean" and "mean_proj" or "BAR 1", "BAR 2", ...

Comment: I'm looking for a way to put 'BAR 1' above the first two bars and 'BAR 2' above the second two bars.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An approach to simulating this is to duplicate traces and use **text** parameters on these traces

```
import pandas as pd 
import plotly.graph_objects as go

test_df = pd.DataFrame({'component':['BAR 1','BAR 2','BAR 3'],'mean':[7.4,7.8,6.5],'mean_proj':[6.8,7.9,8.4]})

def barchart2(df,x1,x2,y):
    fig = go.Figure()
    fig.add_trace(go.Bar(name=x1,x=df[x1],y=df[y],marker_color='#221435')),
    fig.add_trace(go.Bar(name=x1,x=df[x1],y=df[y],marker_color='rgba(0,0,0,0)', text=x1, showlegend=False)),
    fig.add_trace(go.Bar(name=x2,x=df[x2],y=df[y],marker_color='rgb(55,177,140)')),   
    fig.add_trace(go.Bar(name=x2,x=df[x2],y=df[y],marker_color='rgba(0,0,0,0)', text=x2, showlegend=False)),

    fig.update_traces(orientation="h", hoverinfo=None, insidetextanchor="start")
    fig.update_xaxes(showgrid=False, zeroline=False)
    fig.update_yaxes(showgrid=False, zeroline=False)
    fig.update_layout(paper_bgcolor='rgba(0,0,0,0)',plot_bgcolor='rgba(0,0,0,0)',bargap=0.20,margin=dict(t=30,b=5,l=25,r=0))
    fig.update_layout(barmode='group')
    # return fig.write_html('test.html',auto_open=True)
    return fig

barchart2(test_df,'mean','mean_proj','component')
```

[image]

#### where y-axis ticks are labels

Same technique.

```
import pandas as pd 
import plotly.graph_objects as go

test_df = pd.DataFrame({'component':['BAR 1','BAR 2','BAR 3'],'mean':[7.4,7.8,6.5],'mean_proj':[6.8,7.9,8.4]})

def barchart2(df,x1,x2,y):
    fig = go.Figure()
    fig.add_trace(go.Bar(name=x1,x=df[x1],y=df[y],marker_color='#221435')),
    fig.add_trace(go.Bar(name=x1,x=df[x1],y=df[y],marker_color='rgba(0,0,0,0)', text=df[y], showlegend=False)),
    fig.add_trace(go.Bar(name=x2,x=df[x2],y=df[y],marker_color='rgb(55,177,140)')),   
    fig.add_trace(go.Bar(name=x2,x=df[x2],y=df[y],marker_color='rgba(0,0,0,0)', text=df[y], showlegend=False)),

    fig.update_traces(orientation="h", hoverinfo=None, insidetextanchor="start")
    fig.update_xaxes(showgrid=False, zeroline=False)
    fig.update_yaxes(showgrid=False, zeroline=False)
    fig.update_layout(paper_bgcolor='rgba(0,0,0,0)',plot_bgcolor='rgba(0,0,0,0)',bargap=0.20,margin=dict(t=30,b=5,l=25,r=0))
    fig.update_layout(barmode='group')
    # return fig.write_html('test.html',auto_open=True)
    return fig.update_yaxes(visible=False)

barchart2(test_df,'mean','mean_proj','component')
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

For anyone who's looking for another way to fix this (without the use of hidden traces) you could also use fig.add_annotations. With add_annotations you can add text on certain places in the graph.

```
import pandas as pd 
import plotly.graph_objects as go

test_df = pd.DataFrame({'component':['BAR 1','BAR 2','BAR 3','BAR 4','BAR 5','BAR 6','BAR 7'],'mean':[7.4,7.8,6.5,7.7,7.4,7.8,6.5],'mean_proj':[6.8,7.9,8.4,6.3,7.9,8.4,6.3]})

def barchart2(df,x1,x2,y,font):
    fig = go.Figure()
    fig.add_trace(go.Bar(name=x1,x=df[x1],y=df[y],orientation='h',hoverinfo=None,marker_color='#221435')),
    fig.add_trace(go.Bar(name=x2,x=df[x2],y=df[y],orientation='h',hoverinfo=None,marker_color='rgb(55,177,140)')),      
    fig.update_xaxes(showgrid=False, zeroline=False,showticklabels=False)
    fig.update_yaxes(showgrid=False, zeroline=False,showticklabels=False)
    fig.update_layout(paper_bgcolor='rgba(0,0,0,0)',plot_bgcolor='rgba(0,0,0,0)',bargap=0.50,
                       margin=dict(t=30,b=5,l=0,r=0),barmode='group',
                       legend=dict(yanchor='bottom',y=-0.1,xanchor='left',x=0,font=dict(family=font,size=25)))  
    startplace = 6.4
    for i in df[y].unique():
      fig.add_annotation(x=0.23,y=startplace,
       text=i,
       showarrow=False,
       font=dict(family=font,color='#EB0045',size=25)),
      startplace = startplace - 1
    return fig.write_html('fig1.html',auto_open=True)

barchart2(test_df,'mean','mean_proj','component','Arial')
```

The code will result in the following graph:

[image]